# Lenovo IdeaPad Z570 touchpad stopped working after upgrade to 15.04

Tags: 15.04, touchpad

Having just upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04 (from 14.04 via 14.10) my touchpad does not appear to be working. It is still however possible to make use of a USB connected mouse.

Following the instructions [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection#Some_general_work_flow_for_Triagers) I have tried to diagnose the problem with the following results:

- Check whether the kernel has detected the Touchpad

  ```
  $ cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep TouchPad
  N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
  ```
- Check whether xserver has detected the Touchpad

  ```
  $ xinput --list | grep TouchPad
  ⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
  ```
- Check whether the synaptics module is correctly loaded in xserver

  ```
  $ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep -i synaptics
  [    33.606] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/event5)
  [    33.606] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "evdev touchpad catchall"
  [    33.606] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
  [    33.606] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
  [    33.606] (**) evdev: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Device: "/dev/input/event5"
  [    33.606] (--) evdev: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Vendor 0x2 Product 0x7
  [    33.606] (--) evdev: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Found 3 mouse buttons
  [    33.606] (--) evdev: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Found absolute axes
  [    33.606] (--) evdev: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Found absolute multitouch axes
  [    33.606] (--) evdev: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Found x and y absolute axes
  [    33.606] (--) evdev: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Found absolute touchpad.
  [    33.606] (II) evdev: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Configuring as touchpad
  [    33.606] (**) evdev: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
  [    33.606] (**) evdev: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
  [    33.606] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 13)
  [    33.606] (II) evdev: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: initialized for absolute axes.
  [    33.606] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
  [    33.606] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration profile 0
  [    33.606] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
  [    33.606] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
  [    33.606] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/mouse1)
  ```
- For problems such as scrolling area, touch area, button wrong mapping, and multitouch

  ```
  $ xinput --list-props 13
  Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
  Device Enabled (116):   1
  Coordinate Transformation Matrix (118): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
  Device Accel Profile (243): 0
  Device Accel Constant Deceleration (244):   1.000000
  Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (245):   1.000000
  Device Accel Velocity Scaling (246):    10.000000
  Device Product ID (236):    2, 7
  Device Node (237):  "/dev/input/event5"
  Evdev Axis Inversion (247): 0, 0
  Evdev Axis Calibration (248):   
  Evdev Axes Swap (249):  0
  Axis Labels (250):  "Abs MT Position X" (269), "Abs MT Position Y" (270), "Abs Pressure" (267), "Abs Tool Width" (268), "None" (0), "None" (0)
  Button Labels (251):    "Button Left" (119), "Button Unknown" (239), "Button Right" (121), "Button Wheel Up" (122), "Button Wheel Down" (123)
  Evdev Scrolling Distance (252): 0, 0, 0
  Evdev Middle Button Emulation (253):    0
  Evdev Middle Button Timeout (254):  50
  Evdev Third Button Emulation (255): 0
  Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (256): 1000
  Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (257):  3
  Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (258):   20
  Evdev Wheel Emulation (259):    0
  Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (260):   0, 0, 4, 5
  Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (261):    10
  Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (262):    200
  Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (263): 4
  Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (264):  0
  ```

I cannot see anything in the results to suggest I have a problem and have yet to find any solutions to similar problems that have worked for me.

I would appreciate any assistance in this matter.

My system information is:

```
$ uname -a
Linux Ideapad-Z570 3.19.0-26-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 11 14:16:45 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try running the command here to enable the touchpad: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2192864#post_12870711

Comment: That did not appear to have any effect. I ran the following and restarted the laptop:

`xinput --set-prop 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad' 'Device Enabled' 1`

Comment: Run the disable one first and then the enable one. Also make sure that the name in quotes is replaced with the name for your touchpad (SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad).

Comment: That still had no effect I'm afraid.

Comment: Maybe try installing `synclient`.

Comment: It was already installed. Thought I had to install `xserver-xorg-core`. But still no luck.

Comment: Did you reboot afterward?

Comment: Ooops! Forgot that. It is working now. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Good. Should I put that as the answer>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27311/discussion-between-j1n3l0-and-zacharee1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because there's something wrong with the `synclient` installation. Reinstall that and reboot.